# Symfony Form Type - add options

Tags: forms, symfony, formbuilder, symfony5

In my project I have 3 entities; User, Module, and UserModule.

User has properties such as id, username, email along with a UserModules property that is a collection of UserModules.

Module has properties id, name and description.

Each UserModule object has properties User(reference to corresponding  User), Module (reference to corresponding module) and Access (boolean for whether or not access is permitted)

My issue is I do not know how to use Symfony's Form types to show all the modules when creating a User.
 I have a number of modules made already (i.e. 'admin', 'ticket', 'help'). In my UserType class my buildForm method looks like:

```
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('modules', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => UserModuleType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false
                ],
            ]);
    }
```

my UserModuleType class is

```
    {
        $builder
            ->add('access', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'No Access' => false,
                    'Full Access' => true,
                ]
            ]);
    }
```

This shows the UserModules assigned to the User, but when creating a User, I want it to already have UserModules already added for each module.

How can I set this up so that the form will use all possible modules to create default UserModules?

Comment: On second thought, maybe I should be adding UserModules to my User class after creating a new user, in my UserController's new action, and before creating a form with it                                                                                                                                           '   $user = new User()                                                                                            
  //code to create and add user modules                                                                             $form -> $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user)'

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will find some help here : 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

in the example : use tags as your modules

Answer (score 0):

In this case, as you are only using true and false for defining if the user has access to a module, I would use the `EntityType` with the `multiple` attribute instead of the `CollectionType`.

This way you only set which modules have access.

[Link to documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)